# Integral over an ImplicitRegion

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, finite-element-method, implicit

I often need to do integrals over surfaces of different geometries ( in my case it's fermi surfaces ). To do so i use the following code

```
s1 = ImplicitRegion[G[x, y]== 0 , {{x, -pi, pi}, {y, -pi, pi}}];
NIntegrate[F[x], {x, y} \[Element] s1]
```

Which is simple. i first define a region over which to integrate and then integrate over that region.

I obtain a very confusing and intriguing error in some ( not all) cases.

```
Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in 
{NIntegrate`SimplexQuadratureDump`P$176172[1]}->{(1/2)(NIntegrate`SimplexQuadratureDump
`S$176172$176174+NIntegrate`SimplexQuadratur
eDump`S$176172$176176),(NIntegrate`SimplexQuadratureDump
`S$176172$176175+<<48>>)/2} cannot be combined.
```

Now this error only happen for some geometries and some functions. to be more specific i tried the following :

```
   G[x_, y_] = 2*t (Cos[x] + Cos[y] ) ;
   F[x]=1
```

it works

```
   G[x_, y_] = 2*t (Cos[x] + Cos[y] ) ;
   F[x]=x
```

it works ( here t=1 ).

But for

```
   G[x_, y_] = 2*t (Cos[x] + Cos[y] ) ;
   F[x]=Cos[x] ;
```

it doesn't work

What's the problem, and what does this error mean ?

this is the exact code i wrote :

```
F[x_, y_] = 2*(Cos[x] + Cos[y]); 
s1 = ImplicitRegion[F[x, y] == 1, {{x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}}]; 
NIntegrate[Cos[x], Element[{x, y}, s1]]
```

PS: exactly the same happens with or without using DiscretizeRegion

Version Number:11.0.0.0
Platform:Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: What values are you using for `t` and `u`? Also, you need to be consistent between `F` and `f`.

Comment: Please post the actual code you used. What is posted does not generate the errors you report. You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Well i am not surprised that you didn't have the error since apparently according to this  [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114704/integrate-function-over-a-2d-implicit-surface). in some cases it doesn't happen which is very confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I filed a bug report for you. Here is a workaround:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
F[x_, y_] = 2*(Cos[x] + Cos[y]);
s1 = ImplicitRegion[F[x, y] == 1, {{x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}}];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[s1, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
FEMNBoundaryIntegrate[Cos[x], {x, y}, bmesh]
3.131461968054968`
```

*update*:

You can also use this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
F[x_, y_] = 2*(Cos[x] + Cos[y]);
s1 = ImplicitRegion[F[x, y] == 1, {{x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}}];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[s1, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
NIntegrate[Cos[x], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
```

Generate a boundary element mesh (see [ToBoundaryMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html)) from the region. `NIntegrate` than figures out that it should do a surface integral.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be working. on the other hand i have no idea what the code means is it possible to have more details the code ?

Comment: @lakehal, I hope this is better?

Comment: well yes now it's much better. although i still want to understand the code better. can you give  refrence on the FEMNBoundaryIntegrate. i tried to look it up i didn't have a result on this as a function. there is something that describes the methode but not it as a function and it's options. from what i understood it's a methode to do integral by descritisation so i would like to know what are the options to increse the precision. and thanks again.

Comment: @lakehal, there is no reference on `FEMNBoundaryIntegrate` - It uses the finite element method to evaluate the argument over the (curved) boundary and then sums things up. To only way to control it is through the boundary mesh, and then is documented in [ToBoundaryMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html)

Comment: Now things are clear. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some things change to better. In version 13 on Windows 10

```
F[x_, y_] = 2*(Cos[x] + Cos[y]);
s1 = ImplicitRegion[F[x, y] == 1, {{x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}}];
NIntegrate[Cos[x], Element[{x, y}, s1]]
```

> `3.13146`

```
Region[s1]
```

[image]

It should be noticed that the notation `Integrate[Cos[x], Element[{x, y}, s1]]` is unclear. Is this a line integral? if so, of which kind?

Addition. I'd like to add that

```
Integrate[Cos[x]*Boole[2*(Cos[x] + Cos[y]) == 1], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> `0`

in order to explain why the notation `Integrate[Cos[x], Element[{x, y}, s1]]` is unclear.

Comment: `NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, s1]]` is arclength, It is a line integrate, `Cos[x]` is a function on a one-dimensional  sub-manifold  on plane, so we  can not use double integrate. Your can read something about Hausdorff measure.

Comment: Distinguish between the integral of a function on a manifold and the integral of a vector field on a manifold. Here  just a function `Cos[x]` on a 1-dimensional sub-manifold.

Comment: @cvgmt: Thank you for your interest to the answer. Where is "`NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, s1]]` is arclength" documented? I am aware about Hausdorff measure.